# What is the Best Practices to remove product listing Magento V1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9

- I am not a programmer - I am only an back-end user. I am trying to learn the best practices to make changes to my website. It was built by a programmer using Magento 1.9.3.1. and I was given access to the Admin panel, but I am on my own to figure out how it works.

I have access to some files using filezilla but I don't know enough about making changes and don't want to "break" things.

I want to delete a product from my site. I see that I could just hit delete from manageproducts/product listing - My question is should I do more or is this the best way to remove the item? IE should I be changing or removing something in the files as "best practice"

Tks - ChunksHouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! You're good. The best practice and only way you should delete a product is through the admin panel. This allows Magento to clean up the database and other related information.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly fine, you should use admin panel as much as to can until you are facing any issue. To delete single or some product its always good to remove them using admin panel. If you had wanted to delete bulk of product at that time magento admin will be bit slow, there you could have gone to remove programatically.